# relative path on different server

Tags: javascript, html

i have link of home page in html page i want it to go to home page when clicked and i have to upload it two different server. i dont want to put static link on that. how can target home page link to there relative homepate path when uploaded on different server.

home page link is 
http://test.niwas.com and 
http://final.niwas.com

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="#">home</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Relative path `/` will work then.

Comment: you mean if i put / in href then it will take us to home page

Comment: ok thank of quick reply i will check and get back to u sir

Comment: You are welcome :) The question is answered now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as it was stated in the comments, you can use relative path `/`.

```
<a href="/">home</a>
```

For other links you can use the same "link system":

```
<a href="/about.html">about</a>
```